# Removing blank spaces in Express Validator

Tags: javascript, regex, express

I'm not very good with regex, but I'm using the following on the frontend with Joi to remove blank spaces from a phone number for validation. It seems to work:

input: `0758541287 8`

***Valid:***

`Joi.string().trim().replace(/\s*/g,"").pattern(new RegExp(/^0([1-6][0-9]{8,10}|7[0-9]{9})$/))`

My server uses `express-validator`, and I'm just surprised that this isn't removing the spaces:

***Not Valid:***

```
body('phone')
    .isString()
    .replace(/\s*/g,"")
    .matches(/^0([1-6][0-9]{8,10}|7[0-9]{9})$/)
    .withMessage('Please enter a UK phone number'),
```

***Also not working:***

```
body('phone')
    .isString()
    .custom(value => Promise.resolve(value.replace(/\s*/g, "")))
    .matches(/^0([1-6][0-9]{8,10}|7[0-9]{9})$/)
    .withMessage('Please enter a UK phone number'),
```

***Validation Error:***

```
  validationErrors: [
    {
      value: '0748431287 8',
      msg: 'Please enter a UK phone number',
      param: 'phone',
      location: 'body'
    }
  ],
```

I could just remove the spaces before I make the request, but I'm interested in knowing why this isnt' behaving as I would imagine?

Comment: im not familiar with `express-validator`, but since you are already removing white spaces using `replace`, you can opt to remove `trim` before it. 

For your problem, `replace` doesn't replace the original string but creates a copy, replaces the characters and returns it. You will need to equate it to the actual variable. If what you meant was it doesn't properly match the regex, you might mean to use `match` instead of `matches`

Comment: Hi @SparkeE - You're right about `trim()`, it's just something I'd forgotten to take out when I added different validation. RE: `replace` - the fact that it returned a new string is what made me think that it was being passed to the next chained function. The docs agree with you in the context of the `custom` function - the value is the original field value, not the new string, but I'm still confused with why Joi seems to work differently? `pattern` is receiving the altered string, no?

Comment: also `matches` appears to be `express-validators` version of `match` from what I can tell. `match` leads to an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [custom validation method](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#customvalidator) returns `undefined` (because that's what `console.log(...)` returns), which is interpreted to mean that the field is invalid.

Moreover, the documentation for [`replace`](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/sanitization-chain-api.html#replacevalues_to_replace-new_value) does not mention regular expressions. Perhaps it replaces only substrings?

Finally, `matches` does not appear in the documentation either.

You can use the normal Javascript functions `replace` and `match` inside a custom validation method:

```js
body("phone")
  .isString()
  .custom(value => value.replace(/\s*/g, "")
                        .match(/^0([1-6][0-9]{8,10}|7[0-9]{9})$/))
  .withMessage("Please enter a UK phone number")
```

Comment: My bad - I've removed the custom validation. Then problem was occuring without it though. I was just using that to see what the `value` was. I've updated the OP.

I'll have a read through that link on replace - but it works in the browser and in that Joi validation, so I was just a bit surprised. Thanks for the link

Comment: See my augmented answer.

Comment: Weird - that's not working either: I've added the validation error to the OP, but it's the standard one you'd get with `express-validator`

Comment: Thanks - that works now (and makes sense I think). So basically `.replace()` is `express-validator`'s sanitizer method, not the JS function, so you have to put the logic in a custom function. You also can't use JS' `replace()` function alone in the custom validator, because it's a validator, not a sanitizer (unlike trim etc), so the value isn't being passed along the chain to the next function. Right? xD

Comment: In other words this allows validation, but I still have to mutate the `req` field elsewhere. Which is fine. What I don't still fully understand is why a string method like `toUpperCase()` works in the chain (whilst not being in `validatorjs'` docs), but something like `replaceAll()` doesn't

Comment: [`toUpperCase()`](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/sanitization-chain-api.html#touppercase) is an `express-validator` method, not a string method.

Comment: well, that explains that then! Thanks for your help!